# Google Chrome (build 84) breaks Javascript event (Uncaught TypeError: timeline.toggleWatcher is not a function)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, chromium

We have a page that appears to have been broken with the latest chrome update (to 84). There's a checkbox with an onclick event, that no longer fires. We're presented with an error: Uncaught TypeError: timeline.toggleWatcher is not a function

attached is the HTML calling this JavaScript function

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right condensed-dropdown">
                    <li>
                        <a class="pos-rel" data-watcher-toggle-type="submitter" data-notify="submitter" data-selected="true" onclick="timeline.toggleWatcher('submitter')">
                        <span class="dropdown-toggle-icon">
                            <i class="fa fw fa-check-square"></i> 
                        </span>
                        <span class="history-filter-label">Submitter</span> </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="pos-rel" data-watcher-toggle-type="analyst" data-notify="analyst" data-selected="false" onclick="timeline.toggleWatcher('analyst')">
                        <span class="dropdown-toggle-icon">
                            <i class="fa fw fa-square-o"></i> 
                        </span>
                        <span class="history-filter-label">Assigned Analyst</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="pos-rel" data-watcher-toggle-type="watcher" data-notify="watcher" data-selected="true" onclick="timeline.toggleWatcher('watcher')">
                        <span class="dropdown-toggle-icon">
                            <i class="fa fw fa-check-square"></i> 
                        </span>
                        <span class="history-filter-label">Watchers</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Has timeline become a reserved word in JavaScript?

Comment: Your page would have been broken in Firefox since April, FYI.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a reserved word. Also, it will work if you use `window.timeline.dosomething`.

The reason you are seeing this problem is because `document` now has [a new property `timeline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/timeline).

Now you may wonder why this matters, you are not writing `document.timeline` but just `timeline`, right? Well, the reason is historical: To make writing inline event handlers simpler and shorter, some things are in their scope which are a bit unexpected today.

The details can be read in the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#internal-raw-uncompiled-handler) (check the instructions under "scope"). Also, [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21975639/1871033) explores this topic further.

You can imagine it as if your code is called within a number of nested `with` blocks:

- `with (document)`
- If the handler is on an element that is inside of a `<form>`: `with (formElement)`
- `with (element)` (the element itself for which you write the handler)

[This article](http://jibbering.com/faq/names/event_handler.html) illustrates it as follows:

> Given the following markup:
>
> ```html
> <p onclick="self.alert(event);"></p>
> ```
>
> The augmented scope chain, if written in ECMAScript, would look like:
>
> ```js
> function onclick(event) {
>   with(document) {
>     with(this.form) {
>       with(this) {
>         self.alert(event);
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

As you can see, the issue is that in this context, `document.timeline` is accessible in your scope as just `timeline`, overriding the global variable with the same name.

The immediate solution is to use `window.timeline` as I wrote above, but going forward, it would be advisable to use `addEventListener` instead anyway, instead of writing inline handlers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Did not know what I was stumbling into...

Answer (score 0):

`timeline` is not a "reserved word", it's a property of `Document`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/timeline

You should add event handlers programmatically rather than using inline attributes in your markup and relying on global variables, which will be shadowed by any new properties added to `Document`.

For example, this works fine:

```html
<html>
    <head><title>Bug Test</title></head>
    <body>
        <button id="btn">Works</button>
        <script>
         
        var timeline = {
            dosomething: function(param){
                alert('doing something: '+param);
            }
        }
        
        document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', event => {
          timeline.dosomething("works");
        });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

After posting, did some more testing... It looks like timeline is in fact a reserved word now. See example HTML below:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Bug Test</title></head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="mgtest.dosomething('hello there')">Works</button>
        <button onclick="timeline.dosomething('hello there')">Does Not Work</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        var mgtest = {
            dosomething: function(param){
                alert('doing something: '+param);
            }
        }

        var timeline = {
            dosomething: function(param){
                alert('doing something: '+param);
            }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: One of the reasons globals are best avoided.