# import environment variable inside html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, environment-variables

I have a maven project with folders like `myproject/src/main/resources/public`. I am using this maven project just to make a war and deploy my UI code (containing HTML5, JavaScript(with jQuery), CSS etc) to tomcat server and nothing java related.

And inside `public` folder, I have `index.html` and `builder.js` files defined.

`index.html` which has the following line:

```
<button type="button" id = "bButton " onclick="location.href='https://myserver-dev.com/Builder/builder.html'">Builder</button>
```

And another JS file `builder.js` where I am setting env variable like this:

```
//  var envURL = "http://localhost:8080";
  var envURL = "https://myserver-dev.com";
  //var envURL = "https://myserver-test.com";
```

I was thinking of creating a separate JS file, maybe something like `properties.js` or `env.js` and put the following in it so that I can just import it in html and js files whenever needed:

```
//  var envURL = "http://localhost:8080";
  var envURL = "https://myserver-dev.com";
  //var envURL = "https://myserver-test.com";
```

If I do that what would be the best way to get the `envURL` inside `index.html` and `builder.js` at appropriate places?

Comment: I wouldn't call that an "environment variable". It's just a global constant within the javascript on your html page in the browser.

Comment: Do you know how to use `<script>` tags?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I can include the `properties.js` file inside HTML file using <script> tag. But how would I included it at `onclick` handler ? For `builder.js`, how can I import the constant inside this file as I can't use `<script>` tag inside a JS file.

Comment: In the onclick handler you'd just refer to the constant, like `location.href = envUrl + '/Builder/builder.html';`. (However, notice that for this purpose you really should use `<a href="/Builder/builder.html">` - relative url -, and [writing event handlers in html is considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6941483/1048572)).

Comment: In the *builder.js* script, you can either simply refer to the global variable and make sure that your html always includes both scripts in the right order using `<script>` tags, or you start off with ES6 modules and `import`/`export` syntax.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. So in the `builder.js` script, I should have access to the global variable  by doing something like  `console.log(envURL)`if I include `properties.js` in `index.html` and `builder.html` using `<script>` tags ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Comment: Ok, great. And for the `index.html` if I go ahead and use `<a href="/Builder/builder.html">`. The whole button would be treated as `hyperlink` and I don't need  to use`<button>` anymore.  Is this what you meant to say? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, prefer hyperlinks over buttons when possible. If you want to make it look more like a button, use `<a class="button">` and style it with a border using CSS.