# What is difference between parameter with ' ' and parameter without ' ' in Template literals (js)

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, template-literals

What is the difference between parameter with quotation and parameter without quotation in Template literals in JavaScript

Why when I put quotation >> ('${key}') it does the function >> fun('${key}') while when I delete quotation >> (${key}) it doesn't do the function >> fun(${key})
what different between  parameter with quotation and parameter without quotation in Template literals with JavaScript

```
for ( let key in states) { 
console.log(key);
var n =states[key].name;
var cur = states[key].currency;
console.log()

con.innerHTML += `<div> <span>name : "  ${n}
     " </span> <br> <span>cur : "  ${cur}
     " </span> </div><br> <span>cur : "  ${key}
     " </span>  <button onclick= fun('${key}')> select </button><hr> `
}

function fun(o) { 
alert(states[o].name);
alert(states[o].currency);
}
```

the code above run the function >> fun('${key}')

```js
for (let key in states) {
  console.log(key);
  var n = states[key].name;
  var cur = states[key].currency;
  console.log()

  con.innerHTML += `<div> <span>name : "  ${n}
         " </span> <br> <span>cur : "  ${cur}
         " </span> </div><br> <span>cur : "  ${key}
         " </span>  <button onclick= fun(${key})> select </button><hr> `
}

function fun(o) {
  alert(states[o].name);
  alert(states[o].currency);
}
```

Comment: If you look at the generated code,  it will be `fun('foo')` vs `fun(foo)`. `'foo'` is a string literal, `foo` is a variable reference.

Comment: Notice that your code doesn't work when `key` contains an apostrophe `'` or angle bracket `>`. Do not construct code as a string - neither with plain concatenation nor with template literals - but instead [use the DOM to attach a function as an event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6941483/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

It just adds `'` in the final string.

The reason why this works in your example, but when you omit them it doesn't is because you are using that to generate `js` code inside an `HTML` handler.

Your keys are strings, so in `js` they need to be enclosed in either `'` or `"`. When you omit them they are treated as variables and most likely you don't have variables (or constants) with that name(s).